# Laravel cannot load 3rd party library

Tags: php, laravel

Basically this is what I've done so far:

I have put my 3rd party library in `app\library\WebName\Helper\Helper.php`.

This is the content of the `Helper.php`

```
namespace WebName\Helper;

class Helper {

    public static function hello() {

        return 'Hello!';
    }
}
```

Then I modified the composer.json:

```
"classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/library",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
```

And then I executed a `composer dump-autoload`.

Now, the problem is that when I try to access the `Helper` class, for example like in this controller:

```
use WebName\Helper;

class ValidationController extends BaseController {

    public function sayHello() {

        // Verification
        echo Helper::hello();
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'WebName\\Helper' not found","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\webname\\app\\controllers\\ValidationController.php","line":19}}
```

Comment: @MarkBaker /facepalm Thank you! It's working now. Please, write down the answer and I'll mark it :) I'm so tired, guess it's time to stop now.

Comment: Namespaces are fun :) And a second set of eyes always helps when you've been staring at something for ages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If class `Helper` is in namespace `WebName\Helper`, then surely you should be using

```
use WebName\Helper\Helper;
```

not

```
use WebName\Helper;
```

in your controller ?