# 3rd Party class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces

Here is what I've done so far.. based on this link [Laravel cannot load 3rd party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029102/laravel-cannot-load-3rd-party-library)

I followed all of it but still Im having this error

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'FileProcess' not found","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\fileshare\\trunk\\app\\controllers\\UserFilesController.php","line":437}}
```

my composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/library",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

then my controller

```
<?php
 use \FileProcess;
 class UserFilesController extends \BaseController {


public function someMethod(){

$fp = new FileProcess;
}
}
```

then my 3rd party class which is located in **app/library/FileProcess.php** folder

```
<?php namespace FileProcess;

class FileProcess
{
   // some methods
}
```

i do not know what is wrong or if there is lacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Laravel can't find the class is because you have namespaced it and when you call it using `use` you are calling it from the Global namespace. Either of the following will fix it for you.

1) Remove `namespace FileProcess;` from the class file

2) In your controller call it using it's namespace `use FileProcess\FileProcess;`